# Install archlinux package pk2cmd-plus on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, package-management, software-installation

I'm quite new to Linux and Ubuntu so please be patient :)

I would like to install the package Archlinux package [pk2cmd-plus](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pk2cmd-plus) on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit to be able to program the Microship PIC18F24K50 with PicKit2. I believe it is a 32bit program. Can I install the package directly somehow? Or do I need to compile it manually, and in that case how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I finally solved it. I had to have the package libusb-dev installed.

This is what I did:

1) I downloaded the source and the new device file from Archlinux, unzipped it, and compiled it.

```
make linux
```

2) Copied the executable and the device file to another folder (according to the readme-file).

```
sudo cp pk2cmd /usr/local/bin/
sudo cp PK2DeviceFile.dat /usr/share/pk2
```

3) Changed user privileges to the binary (before doing this I had to run pk2cmd as root).

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/local/bin/pk2cmd
```

4) Updated .bashrc with the line.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/pk2
```

And now it works :)

```
mikael@computer:~$ pk2cmd -?v

Executable Version:    1.21.00
Device File Version:   1.63.148
OS Firmware Version:   2.32.00
```